# syntax for 2 left joins in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, group-by, left-join

This query runs fine and gives me an output like this:

```
[(1, 9), (2, 12), (4, 14), (6, 14)]
```

```
    query = """
    SELECT users.id,
       count(tasks.userId)
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON users.id = tasks.userId
    WHERE tasks.completed = FALSE
    GROUP BY users.id
    """
```

However, when I add another left join, it does not give me accurate results:

```
    query = """
    SELECT users.id,
       count(tasks.userId), count(songs.userId)
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON users.id = tasks.userId
    LEFT JOIN songs ON users.id = songs.userId
    WHERE tasks.completed = FALSE
    GROUP BY users.id
    """
```

The result should look like this:

```
[(1, 9, 10), (2, 12, 10), (4, 14, 10), (6, 14, 10)]
```

but instead, my result looks like this:

```
[(1, 90, 90), (2, 120, 120), (4, 140, 140), (6, 140, 140)]
```

which looks like the value of `tasks x 10`as both, count(tasks) and count(song)
what am I missing out on?

The idea of `count(tasks.userId)`was to find the number of tasks where the userId matched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate separately in `tasks` and `songs` and then join `users` to the results of the aggregations:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       COALESCE(t.count_tasks, 0) count_tasks,
       COALESCE(s.count_songs, 0) count_songs
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT userId, COUNT(*) count_tasks
  FROM tasks 
  WHERE completed = FALSE
  GROUP BY userId
) t ON u.id = t.userId
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT userId, COUNT(*) count_songs
  FROM songs  
  GROUP BY userId
) s ON u.id = s.userId;
```

I'm not sure if you actually want `LEFT` joins (at least for the table `tasks`), because in your code, the 1st query that you say returns what you expect, although it contains a `LEFT` join, the join is actually an `INNER` join because the condition `WHERE tasks.completed = FALSE` returns only the matching rows.

Comment: why do we use coalesce here? any alternatives?

Comment: @x89 you are using LEFT joins. In the results there may exist users with no tasks or no songs related to them. In this case the result for count_tasks or count_songs would be null. COALESCE() is used to return 0 instead of null.

Comment: ah yes. how could we modify this in case of inner joins then

Comment: @x89 use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN and `SELECT u.id, t.count_tasks, s.count_songs ....`